# How to recall search pattern when writing replace regex pattern in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim

Here's the scenario: I've got a big file filled with all sorts of eclectic rubbish that I want to regex. I fiddle around and come up with a perfect search pattern by using the <kbd>/</kbd> command and seeing what it highlights.

Now I want to use that pattern to replace with. So, I start typing <kbd>:%s/</kbd> and I cannot recall what the pattern was. Is there some magical keyboard command that will pull in my last search pattern here? If I'm writing a particularly complex regex, I have even opened up a new MacVim window, typed the regex from the first window into a buffer there, then typed it back into the Vim window when writing the replace pattern. There has got to be a better way of doing so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found my own answer after having written up the question: Vim tips lists it as [substitute last search](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1501) and can be done in one of two ways.

1. Using an empty search:

   :%s//replace/g
2. By pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> then <kbd>/</kbd> to recall the material from the search buffer (<kbd>/</kbd> - you can use any other named buffer by substituting the <kbd>/</kbd> for the letter representing that buffer).

Comment: Sorry for the self-answer, folks. I did have difficulty actually finding the answer so felt it was worth putting up. And Meta says it is okay to answer your own questions - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Comment: If you end up needing to use more than one arcane regex to sift through your eclectic rubbish, it might be useful to maintain them in variables, using `:let b:tires_sifter = @/` for one type of rubbish, and `:let b:pope_on_a_ropes_sifter = @/` later after you've figured out how to locate the instances of that entity that one can never have too many of.  Pull them out by assigning them back to `@/`, building an `exec` line to use them, or using the `search()` (IIRC.. maybe `matchadd`) function.

Answer (score 4):

There is a `/` register that contains the current search pattern, so you can insert the search pattern into whatever you are typing (either in insert mode or on the command line) with `<CTRL-R>/`

Answer (score 1):

Another option:  after entering the pattern with `<CTRL-R>/`, edit the command line with `<CTRL-F>`.

:help cmdwin